# Is it possible to run python in the web with github.io?

Tags: python, web, github

I want to run a python file in the web I have in a GitHub repository. Is it possible to do this?

And by running in the web, I mean putting `#!/usr/bin/python` and `print 'Content-type:text/html\n` in the first two lines.

Comment: this is a little unclear -- are you looking for something like [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/)?  or are you trying to use a python script to generate output that will be viewable on a web page?  for the latter, you'll need to use a web server like bottle or flask

Comment: https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide

Answer (score 32):

In general this is not possible, Github (pages) serves only static content (ex: HTML, CSS, JS). If you want python to run (ex generate dynamic content) you need a web server capable of running python (your browser were the contents of GitHub Pages get downloaded and run can't do it).

That said there are experimental ways of running subsets of python in the browser. Take a look for a example at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155551/python-in-browser-how-to-choose-between-brython-pypy-js-skulpt-and-transcrypt).

Comment: And what about angular material pages?

Comment: @NabinKhadka yes, that would be possible because angular is a frontend technology. The static code (HTML, CSS, JS) gets downloaded from GitHub to the browser and runs there.

Comment: Thank you elyase. Will dig into it. +1

Comment: Thank you elyase. Does this mean that in the case of GitHub pages serving static content, the browser is the HTTP server also in addition to being the client ?

Answer (score -2):

If you truly want to generate a complete HTTP response via standard output, then start by reading about [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGI) and Python's standard [`cgi` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html). You'll also need to have access to a CGI-compatible web server, perhaps running on a virtual host.

However, CGI is quite obsolescent as a way to produce dynamic output for the web. @jjwon's suggestion to look at [Python-based web application frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#Python) like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) is a good one.

Comment: Oh yeah, I have worked with cgi before, do you know how to get it working with github?

Comment: What does "get it working with github" mean? Are you trying to use GitHub's servers as your personal web server? They are unlikely to be cool with that. :-P

Comment: "CGI is quite obsolescent", sure it is, but it is fine since it follows the KISS principle.

Comment: @user877329, I don't understand. I recommended it because it's a literal solution to the original question, but I suspect it's not **really** what the OP is looking for :-P